# Why is my function (is_crowd) not printing, I'm getting <function is_crowd at 0xf6e128e4>?

Tags: python, function

What the title says, my function isn't working, how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
def is_crowd(people):
  # Write your function here.
  if people >= 30:
    return 'a crowd'
  elif people == 3:
    return 'a crowd'
  else:
    return 'no crowd'
  
# Write the rest of your program here.
crowd = int(input('Number of people: '))
print(f"There's {is_crowd} here!")
```

What it outputs:

```
Number of people: 48
There's <function is_crowd at 0xf6e128e4> here!
```

Comment: You probably intended to write `print(f"There's {is_crowd(crowd)} here!")`

Comment: ```is_crowd(crowd)```. You need to call the function to print the returned value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `()` to print the returned value of the function. Or, simply putting `is_crowd` will print its memory location: `<function .... at 0x....>`

```
print(f"There's {is_crowd(value)} here!")
```

Comment: @PranavBorse no problem